# import matplotlib & Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, pip, conda

I'm using Visual Studio Code and want to be able to use numpy and matplotlib. The code I have is simply:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The first line works fine, but the second line returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\(username)\OneDrive\College\Code\Python\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\(username)\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 205, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\(username)\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 190, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

However, I do know that I have matplotlib installed on Anaconda, as trying to install it using pip tells me that Requirement already satisfied.

I'm using Visual Studio Code with Python 3.7.6 on 64-bit Windows with Anaconda.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you certain that VSCode is using the correct Conda environment? As an aside, why use pip to install matplotlib?

Comment: I am certain that VSCode is using the correct Conda environment (at the bottom left, it says "Python 3.7.6 64-bit ('base': conda).

Comment: You should use a new environment for each project/application, using the base environment for everything will lead to things breaking, doubly so if you're using pip. You should consider removing and installing Conda again.

Comment: Ok, I've removed and installed Conda again, and set up a new environment per the instructions at https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

However, in Visual Studio Code the environment is not being detected for some reason (when I select python interpreter, it only has the base as an option). I'm not sure where to go from here. How do I get Visual Studio Code to detect the new environment?

Also tbh I've used pip because I forgot conda can do the exact same thing, but in both cases the requirement is already satisfied.

Comment: Fixed, see answer below. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, reinstalled Anaconda, then created a new environment, then used pip to force-install:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-install matplotlib
```

numpy and matplotlib now work perfectly fine :)

Comment: the switch should be --force-reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE (Visual Studio Code) is using some environment to run python: it can be anaconda, and it can be something different. The fact that you installed it on anaconda may not be enough, as you need to make sure the visual studio is needed running anaconda environment.

See the following guide: [How to create and manage Python environments in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Per above comment, I am certain that VSCode is using the correct Conda environment (at the bottom left, it says "Python 3.7.6 64-bit ('base': conda).